# Cannot select the radio button using javascript when the page is in an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, radio-button

I have an iframe on the first page that contains a second page. The iframe does not have an id so I'll have to assign one to it using javascript. After I assign the id I try to use javascript to click the radio button that have the value 'female' in it. However when I do, I get an error in the console that says: "ERROR: Execution of script 'categorize faces' failed! Cannot read property 'click' of null". What am I doing wrong?

```
var myframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
myframe.id = "newID";
document.getElementById("newID").contentWindow.document.querySelector("input[value='female']").click();
```

**First Page:**

```
<iframe src="http://chatwithibot.com/test2.php"></iframe>
```

**Second Page:**

```
<form action="/testx.php" method = "POST">
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Firstly why do you look for something that you've already got? `myframe` is already the iframe that you are looking for. Secondly if the iframe you are trying to access isn't in the same domain as the host page, it's unlikely that you'll be able to control it.

Comment: To use javascript to set the ID since the iframe doesn't initially have an ID. Also, it's in the same domain. What would I need to correct to make it work?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]` was already the iframe that you were looking for.

Comment: @customcommander So how do I fix this? Can you write an example code below?

Comment: What is this: `categorize faces`...it has a space in the name? Is that a PHP feature?

Comment: @frosty Review Demo 2 of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54384999/2813224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [`window.frames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames), [`.contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument), & [`.contentWindow.document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow)

### Iframe Exists when Page Loaded (Not Dynamic)

#### See Demo 1

Assuming that we are referencing the first (or only) iframe on the page:

> ```
> window.frames[0]
> document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument; // interchangeable
> document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.document; // interchangeable
> ```

Store any **one of the three lines** from the example above into a variable, then treat that variable as `document`.

> ```
> var iframeDoc = window.frames[0];
> var iframeInput = iframeDoc.querySelector('#input2');
> ```

That in a nutshell is how to access a tag from parent page to a child page via iframe programmatically. If a user's interaction is involved such the user clicking a radio button of the child page then the iframe's document should be registered to the click event using [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or an **[Onevent Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)**.

> ```
> iframeDoc.addEventListener('click', eventHandler);
> ```

The **Event Handler** is a function called when `iframeDoc` is clicked.

> ```
> function eventHandler(event) {
>   console.log(event.target.value);
> }
> ```

`eventHandler()` passes the **[Event Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)** and then references the property **[Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)**. `event.target` is a direct reference to the clicked tag (ex. a radio button). The `.value` property is suffixed to `event.target` to get the value of the clicked tag.

---

### Iframe is Dynamically Inserted Into DOM

#### See Demo 2

When a tag is dynamically added to the DOM it cannot be registered to any event. A workaround is to use the **[Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)** pattern by registering an ancestor tag (ex. body) of the dynamic tag (ex. iframe). The eventHandler must *"drill down"* into the iframe document from an ancestor tag on the parent page. See **Demo 2** for the gruesome details.

---

### Demo 1

#### Static Iframe

**Note:** due to security measures on SO, iframes are crippled. The iframe in this demo is using `srcdoc` to roughly represent what the OP (**O**riginal **P**ost) code has.

```js
var xFrame = window.frames[0];

xFrame.onclick = extractValue;

function extractValue(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

```html
<iframe srcdoc='<form action="/testx.php" method="POST"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br><input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>'></iframe>
```

---

### [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/T8N1Dt/)

### Demo 2

#### Dynamic Iframe

**Note:** a working demo can be reviewed at this **[Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/T8N1Dt/)**

```js
/* 
|| This is to simulate the iframe being dynamically inserted into the DOM.
|| This is not required for OP (Original Post) specific circumstance.
*/
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<iframe src='test2.html'></iframe>`);

/* BEGINNING OF REQUIRED CODE */
/*
|| Register the body to the click event
|| function extractValue() is the event handler called when body is clicked.
*/
document.body.addEventListener('click', extractValue);

/* Event Handler */
/*
|| Reference the Document Object inside iframe
|| Reference the form tag inside Document Object of iframe
|| Reference all radio buttons name='gender' in the form tag
|| Reference the selected radio button
|| Log the selected radio button's value
*/
function extractValue(e) {
  var xFrame = window.frames[0];
  var xForm = xFrame.forms[0];
  var xRads = xForm.elements['gender'];
  var selected = xRads.checked;
  console.log(selected.value);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use javascript to automatically select the radio button with the value of "female" inside an iframe. I tried both your codes, and none of them automatically selects the radio button with the value of "female" inside the iframe.

Comment: Try running `extractValue()` without the click handler. But changer the last 2 lines: `var xRads = xForm.elements['gender'];  var selected = xRads.checked;` to `var xRads = xForm.elements['gender'];  var female = Array.from(xRads).filter(function(rad) { return rad.value === 'female';});`